# Why Python Vincent map visuzalization does not map data from Data Frame?

Tags: python, vincent

I am using `Python` `vincent` map visualization with the use of this package [introductory examples](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/charts_library.html#simple-map). I work in `ipython notebook`.

I defined simple `pandas` `DataFrame` with country FIPS codes (taken from [here](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countrycodes/countrycodes_a.htm)). Then I tried to map `DataFrame` data with `vincent` map by these FIPS codes, but **resulted visualization fails to colour countries in any manner**. How can I make it work?

```
country_data_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'country_names' : np.array(['Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Australia', 'Austria']),
                                 'country_FIPS' : np.array(['032', '051', '036', '040']),
                                 'my_rate' : np.array([0.254, 0.3456, 0.26, 0.357])})
country_data_tmp.head()
```

[image]

```
world_topo = r'world-countries.topo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
             'url': world_topo,
             'feature': 'world-countries'}]

vis = vincent.Map(data=country_data_tmp, 
                  geo_data=geo_data, 
                  scale=1100, 
                  data_bind='my_rate', 
                  data_key='country_FIPS',
                  map_key={'counties': 'properties.FIPS'})

vis.display()
```

[image]

Comment: Does my answer get you to where you need?  If there's anything else you need - happy to discuss / clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't display because you have not set the `map_key` correctly. The `world_countries.topo.json` file identifies the countries by 3 letter code, named `id` in that file (this corresponds to the field called `alpha-3` in the [page you linked to](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countrycodes/countrycodes_a.htm)).  You can see this if you look at [the raw data in that json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrobstory/vincent_map_data/master/world-countries.topo.json).

Also, you set `'name': 'countries'` in `geo_data`, but in `map_key` you try to reference it as `counties` (note the missing `r`). Easy mistake to make, as it's `counties` in the example page where they're mapping US counties.

If you change the variable names so that they reference non-empty fields - you'll get a lovely map as `country_alpha3` in your data table matches `id` in the JSON variable `countries`.

***N.B.*** As your code stands, only the countries for which you have data will be plotted. You could add a layer with all country outlines as [per the second example here](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/charts_library.html#simple-map) if you want all outlined, but only the ones with data coloured.  I've provided changes to the code to do that in the second code / output section below.

***N.B. 2*** With your current values of `my_rate` the colour contrast is not very noticeable.  Try it out with `[0,0.3,0.7,1.0]` to convince yourself it is colouring them differently.

#### Code

```
#Data setup bit - Input[1] from your notebook
#Note new name for country code country_alpha3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

country_data_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'country_names' : np.array(['Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Australia', 'Austria']),
                                 'country_alpha3' : np.array(['ARG','ARM','AUS','AUT']),
                                 'my_rate' : np.array([0.254, 0.3456, 0.26, 0.357])})
country_data_tmp.head()

#map drawing bit Input[2] from your notebook
#Note the changes in variable names

world_topo = r'world-countries.topo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
             'url': world_topo,
             'feature': 'world-countries'}]

vis = vincent.Map(data=country_data_tmp, 
                  geo_data=geo_data, 
                  scale=1100, 
                  data_bind='my_rate', 
                  data_key='country_alpha3',
                  map_key={'countries': 'id'})

vis.display()
```

#### Output

[image: Output of script with sample data]

#### Code with outline layer plus data layer (coloured for those with data):

```
#Replace input[2] with this to add a layer with outline only

world_topo = r'world-countries.topo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
             'url': world_topo,
             'feature': 'world-countries'},
           {'name': 'countries_outline',
             'url': world_topo,
             'feature': 'world-countries'}]

vis = vincent.Map(data=country_data_tmp, 
                  geo_data=geo_data, 
                  scale=100, 
                  data_bind='my_rate', 
                  data_key='country_alpha3',
                  map_key={'countries': 'id'})

del vis.marks[1].properties.update
vis.marks[1].properties.enter.stroke.value = '#000'

vis.display()
```

#### Output (output layer plus data layer)

[image: Image with countries outlined - those with data coloured]

Comment: J Richard Snape, thank you a lot for this full answer! It is more than I expected - I mean `countries_outline` and `del vis.marks[1].properties.update
vis.marks[1].properties.enter.stroke.value = '#000'` elements.

Comment: Any Idea on how to display country names in the Map?